# Round to nearest 30 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have a product line that is sold on a 90 day basis with the lowest denomination being 1 per month. How long the product lasts is based on user's consumption.

Some examples:

If the product lasts 28 days, then I need my JavaScript to change the number of units sold to 2 per month.

If the product lasts 35 days, leave number of units sold as 1 per month.

If the product lasts 61 days, leave number of units sold as 1 per month.

If product lasts 10 days, change to 3 per month.

```
var unitsPerMonth = 0;
var numberOfDays = productsAmount / userConsumption;
// example 1500 / 52 per day = product will last 28 days, so round unitsPerMonth to 2
```

Comment: You need to explain the algorithm better. As it stands, there is no logic to determine why 10 goes to 3, 28 to two and 35 to one. Based on 30 day months, 10 and 28 should both go to 3 as they are both less than 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Math.ceil` which rounds a number up to a whole number.

```
var numberOfDays = productsAmount / userConsumption;
var salesPer30Days = 30 / numberOfDays;
var unitsPerMonth = Math.ceil(salesPer30Days);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you :)